# Python to use map like scala

Tags: scala, pyspark

I have a scala program which has a dataframe and converts it to a list with this statement.

Sample `df` :

```
df = spark_session.createDataFrame([
        ("key", "a,b,c")
    ]

val list=df.rdd.map(r=>r.getString(0)).collect.toList.flatMap(_.split(",")).filter(p=> !p.contains(primaryKey))
```

I need to write similar statement in `PySpark` but `r=>r.getString(0)` does not work in `PySpark`. How can I do this?

Comment: Can you provide some sample data?

Comment: I added some sample data

Answer (score 2):

In scala `r => r.getString` is an anonymous function, also called a lambda function. One issue with your code is you are using Scala's lambda syntax rather than python's. The equivalent lambda in python would be: `lambda r: r.getString(0)`, assuming `r` has a `.getString` method.

Similarly in scala `_.` is shorthand for a lambda where you only use the variable once, but it is equivalent to the above `r=>r.` kind of style. Python doesn't have this kind of shorthand, to my knowledge, so you will just use a regular lambda like above.

The code in python would be roughly:

`result_lst = df.rdd.map(lambda r: r.getString(0)).collect.toList.flatMap(lambda x: x.split(",")).filter(lambda p: not p.contains(primaryKey))`

Comment: Sorry to edit the question again, actually my full statement looks like above in scala

Comment: I am relatively new to pthon so no idea how to pull this off

Answer (score 1):

Below is a Python version of the Scala code with a couple of changes:

1. The 2nd element in your sample data is retrieved as the 1st element is not `split`-able
2. `collect` is performed at the end to leverage PySpark's`flatMap`

```py
df = spark.createDataFrame([
  ("key1", "aa,bb,cc"),
  ("key2", "ii,jj,kk")
]).toDF("key", "value")

df.show()
+----+--------+
| key|   value|
+----+--------+
|key1|aa,bb,cc|
|key2|ii,jj,kk|
+----+--------+

primaryKey = "k"

resultRDD = df.rdd.map(lambda r: r[1]).flatMap(lambda v: v.split(",")).filter(lambda p: not primaryKey in p)

resultRDD.collect()
['aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'ii', 'jj']
```

Comment: Yes this worked. Thanks !, I am getting it now. Can you also take a look at this another question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52677157/window-functions-partitionby-over-a-list