# Window Functions partitionBy over a list

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a dataframe tableDS
In scala I am able to remove duplicates over primary keys using the following -

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window.partitionBy
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.row_number

val window = partitionBy(primaryKeySeq.map(k => tableDS(k)): _*).orderBy(tableDS(mergeCol).desc)
tableDS.withColumn("rn", row_number.over(window)).where($"rn" === 1).drop("rn")
```

I need to write a similar thing in python. primaryKeySeq is a list in python. I tried the first statement like this -

```
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
import pyspark.sql.functions as func

window = Window.partitionBy(primaryKeySeq).orderBy(tableDS[bdtVersionColumnName].desc())
tableDS1=tableDS.withColumn("rn",rank().over(window))
```

This does not give me the correct result.

Answer (score 1):

It got solved - 
Here is the final conversion.

```
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
from pyspark.sql.functions import row_number

window = Window.partitionBy(primaryKeySeq).orderBy(tableDS[bdtVersionColumnName].desc())
tableDS1=tableDS.withColumn("rn", row_number.over(window)).where(tableDS["rn"] == 1).drop("rn")
```